# how to make swipeable UItableview header to show delete button like cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom header which is sub class of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` I want to add the delete button similar to `UITableViewCell` to this header,
I have gone through the internet and found some open source libraries to create swipeable cell which only extend the functionality of `UITableviewCell` which actually I don't need for the time,

What I actually want is to create a swipeable header View to show the delete button on swipe.

Answer (score 0):

There is not out of the box solution for this. However we can still do it by our own custom delete button. The idea is to have a `UIButton` under the header content view and animate it when swiping on header.

Ray Wenderlichs has a great tutorial for [How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)
Use the same logic for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and you are good to go.