# swipe header view same like tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

How can I swipe header view same like tableview cell can any one please help me out

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "RequestHeaderCell", bundle: nil)
    tableVIew.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "RequestHeaderCell")
 }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header: RequestHeaderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "RequestHeaderCell") as! RequestHeaderCell
    let userData = requestData[section]
    header.userData = userData
    return header
}. // how can I make this swipe to right
```

height for header view:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 90
}
```

headerView class:

```
 class RequestHeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
 }
```

Comment: check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301970/how-to-make-swipeable-uitableview-header-to-show-delete-button-like-cells

Answer (score 1):

Simply return  **cell.contentView** instead of cell within your **viewForHeaderInSection** function may be your problem will be resolved.

Comment: u mean header.contentView ?

Comment: when I add header.contentView it crashes and gives me Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView's contentView must remain a direct subview of it. Unexpected superview of the contentView: <UITableView: 0x10706e000; frame = (0 84; 414 652); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2825d7120>; layer = <CALayer: 0x282b2e4a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 128}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}